# GEF: Is EditPart.performRequest(Request) not called when edit part gets selected?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-gef

When clicking on `EditParts` that are not selected yet (hence no "direct edit request"), the `EditPart`s method `performRequest(Request)` is not called.

Is that how it's supposed to be? If so, what does a `Request`of type `REQ_SELECTION`indicate? The documentation says it "Indicates selection Requests", which I assumed would be the above scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `performRequest()` method is called in two places: when the user double clicks on an element and when the user clicks **after** the `EditPart` has already been selected. In the first case, the method is called with a `REQ_OPEN` request, and in the second case it is called with a `REQ_DIRECT_EDIT` request.

Other request (like `REQ_SELECTION`) are not passed to the `EditPart`. They are used to find a matching `EditPolicy` that can handle the request and then passed to this `EditPolicy`. Why this is not the case with these two requests is something I never understood, but that is how things work.

Answer (score 0):

EditPart is selected by calling EditPart#setSelected(...). This method gets called from the SelectionManager, but best way to select something would be calling EditPartViewer#appendSelection(EditPart).

EditPart#performRequest() in my experience is called for requests created programatically automatically in response for other requests. Implementation of the #perfromRequest(Request) is left to the api client. Given that there is #setSelected(...) available on the editpart not sure why one would call #performRequest(Request). Most of the requests are passed to an editpart to create a command for execution EditPart#getCommand(Request)

If there is something particular you'd like to do with the selection look at the following:
SelectionTool and TargetingTool #handleButtonDown() and #handleButtonDown() methods. The tool updates editpart under mouse and set the drag tracker for the tool based on the editpart under mouse Hence also see SelectEditPartTracker.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was trying to distinguish between simple clicks and drag events (which was not possible with a normal selection listener, as both would trigger the same event). But it seems like this method won't work neither :)